# Play Framework error when running app ProvisionException: Unable to provision, Error injecting contstructor, com.google.inject.util.Module

Tags: playframework

Today I am trying to run my Play Framework app that was working yesterday.  I have made no code changes.  I ran `clean`, `compile`, and then `run` to launch the application.  There were no errors in `sbt` but in the browser I received:

```
[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, @766c242kk: Configuration error in :83
  at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.<init>(Messages.scala:482)
  at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.class(Messages.scala:482)
  while locating play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi
  while locating play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
    for parameter 0 at play.i18n.MessagesApi.<init>(MessagesApi.java:32)
  at play.api.i18n.I18nModule.bindings(I18nModule.scala:14):
Binding(class play.i18n.MessagesApi to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.i18n.MessagesApi

1 error]
```

Here is the function that is causing this error in my Application controller:

```
public Result index() {
    // Check that the email matches a confirmed user before we redirect
    Http.Session session = ctx().session();
    String email = ctx().session().get("email");
    if (email != null) {
        User user = User.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null && user.validated) {
            boolean isAuth = AccessMiddleware.isAuthenticated();
            if (isAuth) {
                RoleType role = AccessMiddleware.getSessionRole();
                if (role != null) {
                    switch (role) {
                    case BA:
                        return GO_BA;

                    case SE:
                        return GO_SE;

                    case BAMANAGER:
                        return GO_BAMANAGER;

                    case SEMANAGER:
                        return GO_SEMANAGER;

                    case ADMIN:
                        return GO_ADMIN;

                    default:
                        return GO_HOME;
                    }
                } else {
                    Logger.debug("Application.index() - No Role - Clearing invalid session credentials");
                    session().clear();
                    return GO_HOME;
                }
            } else {
                Logger.debug("Application.index() - No user authenticated - Clearing invalid session credentials");
                session().clear();
                return GO_HOME;
            }
        } else {
            Logger.debug("Application.index() - Clearing invalid session credentials");
            session().clear();
        }
    }

    return ok(index.render(form(Register.class), form(Login.class), playAuth));
}
```

It occurs on the `return ok` statement at the end of the function.

I found a few posts, but the answers did not fix my issue:

[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, in play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862314/provisionexception-unable-to-provision-in-play-framework)

[ProvisionException: Unable to provision. Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324523/provisionexception-unable-to-provision-play-framework)

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was text in the `conf > messages` file that was not formatted properly.

I corrected the `messages` file and it ran fine.

This was not caught in compiling.